# Converting array of primitives to ArrayLIst of String

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, arraylist

I have a method which converts the Object ( which is an array of primitive or strings) which i have got after invocation of a method (so its in instance of java.lang.Object). I want to build the ArrayList from the input array.
I tried using new ArrayList

I have coded something like this

```
private List<String> getListOfStringForPrimitives( Object inputObject ) {
     Class<?> inputClass = null;
    if (inputObject != null) {
        inputClass = inputObject.getClass();
    // Returns true if the inputObject is an Array
        if (isTypeAnArray(inputClass.getName())) {
            Class<?> componentType = inputClass.getComponentType();
            // If the inputObject is array of primitives build the list of Strings from the inputObject
            if (isTypePrimitive(componentType.getName())) {
                //ArrayList <String> arryList;
               // build an array list of Strings. from the inputObject and return.
            }
        }
    }
    return arryList;
```

}

I am stuck how to build the ArrayList from input array!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `java.lang.reflect.Array` to get the primitive values from the primitive array, and then add the boxed equivalents (e.g. `Integer`) to the ArrayList.

Write a set of if-then-else clauses that compare componentType to `Integer.TYPE`, `Character.TYPE`, etc. In each clause, write the appropriate call to the Array class to get the primitives, and then pass them to Whatever.valueOf, and then stick the results into your Array List.

Comment: We can do that if we know the array is of type int. It can be of int, float, double short or boolean, String(object) in my case. And type I am getting dynamically in the method before hand we don't know that array is of type what.

Comment: So write a big if/then/else statement. There are only a fixed set of primitive types. You need a different line of code for each.

Comment: I am not sure if we can do this. Can you show code? and wht about complexity? of putting big if/else?

Comment: @bmargulies : do you mean using Array.getInt(inputObject,index)? how shall i get the lengh of the array? I cannot cast inputObject to Object[] and use .length property.

Comment: @sma this is what the language is like. Yes it will look a bit messy. No I'm not aware of any shortcut. When you get this deep in reflection, you end up with a lot of code.

Comment: @java Array.getLength() will hand you the length on a platter.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the isArray method: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/Checkifthegivenobjectisanarrayprimitveornative.htm

Comment: how will it help to build an arrayList of Strings from input array like [1,2,3,4] ?